# rollup build generating grouped d.ts files, and not individual

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rollupjs

I am building a UI library. When I import my UI library components in another project how can I have individual `d.ts` files per component and not grouped together?

For example, the below is for both Button and Input when I inspect the types of the Button

```
import React from 'react';

interface ButtonProps {
    label: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
    onClick?: () => void;
    size?: "sm" | "md" | "lg";
}
declare const Button: ({ label, disabled, onClick, size }: ButtonProps) => React.JSX.Element;

interface InputProps {
    disabled?: boolean;
    onChange?: () => void;
    placeholder?: string;
}
declare const Input: ({ disabled, onChange, placeholder }: InputProps) => React.JSX.Element;

export { Button, Input };
```

But I would like it to be as below when inspecting types of the Button (`Button.d.ts`)

```
import React from 'react';

interface ButtonProps {
    label: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
    onClick?: () => void;
    size?: "sm" | "md" | "lg";
}
declare const Button: ({ label, disabled, onClick, size }: ButtonProps) => React.JSX.Element;

export { Button };
```

Here is my rollup config:

```
export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      terser(),
    ],
    external: ["react", "react-dom", "styled-components"],
  },
  {
    input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [dts()],
  },
];
```